# ASP.NET 5 Class Library (Package) fails to create

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm adding a new project as Class Library (Package) to my solution and I'm getting errors in project.json.

> .NET Platform 5.4 error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.CSharp >= 4.0.1-beta-23516 could not be resolved.
>   .NET Platform 5.4 error NU1001: The dependency System.Collections >= 4.0.11-beta-23516 could not be resolved.
>   1>C:\Projects\iSeekDevelopments\Source\ISeek.MyProperty.Core\project.json(15,24,15,24): .NET Platform 5.4 error NU1001: The dependency System.Linq >= 4.0.1-beta-23516 could not be resolved.
>   .NET Platform 5.4 error NU1001: The dependency System.Runtime >= 4.0.21-beta-23516 could not be resolved.
>   .NET Platform 5.4 error NU1001: The dependency System.Threading >= 4.0.11-beta-23516 could not be resolved.

Why does it try to reference 4.0.11-beta-23516?
How could it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Running `dnu restore` fixed the issue.